# ATS policy issue when using a redirect url in Swift

Tags: swift, http, https, app-transport-security

I am using this [link](http://app.1337frankfurt.de/menu_images/IMG-20200116-WA0023.jpg) for example to load the link. Although the link is a http link it will be redirected to a https link. It works in the browser.
However, as soon as I let my iOS Application load the resource it will say "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.".

I am using [this library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to load the picture. Is it not supported that Swift loads the https resource? I could think of that ATS blocks the connection to the server so the redirect can't even be received.

I would be very thankful for any thoughts on this.

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you certainly can disable the entirety of ATS using the solutions provided by Kishan and Johnson, if you know the domain of the http resource you are trying to load, you have better options.  For details of why the disabling of ATS entirely is not the best idea, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45783122/3708242).

Better options are:

1. If you know the http resource is always going to give you a redirect to the same https:// url, why not simply use the https:// url in your code.  This won't work if the redirect is dynamic, but if your code is trying to load http://www.example.com/resource and that always redirects to https://www.example.com/resource, why not just change your code to go to the https version.
2. Only disable ATS for the domain in where you need to allow non https connections. This allows you to only allow http connections for domains you know don't support https, better protecting your application users. 
   Your ATS settings in your info.plist wqould look something like this:

[image: Info.plist settings for domain specific ATS settings]

3. If and only if your urls are driven by data that you don't control (i.e. the domains in those urls could be anything), you will need to disable all of ATS, and Apple may eventually want you to provide justification for disabling it.  Originally they were going to have all ATS disabled apps go through an additional justification request processs, but they haven't mentioned that recently.  This should be a last resort.

[image: ATS settings for disabling ATS entirely]

Honestly, looking at your example UR

Answer (score -1):

Go to `info.plist` add a term called `App Transport Security Settings`.

And under that add `Allow Arbitrary Loads`